# Code Coverage in Production is reflecting as 0% (No coverage data)

Tags: trigger, unit-test

Can any one help on this.I have two triggers with their test classes.Using changesets i have moved into production.In Sandbox for trigger1 i.e caseDuplication Test the code coverage was 90% and for trigger2 i.e Reparent Comment the code coverage was 62%.Now when i moved into production the Code coverage is reflecting as 0%.will the trigger work or any alternative i need to do.Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: Check for any test failures. Post some codes

Comment: @highfive:i didnt get your point.

Comment: where are you checking your code coverage in prod ? you should use Developer Console to run all your tests and get the accurate code coverage.

Comment: @ Vamsi Krishna:Once the triggers got deployed into production ,i was checking for the code in apex trigger.Once we open the code ,we have the Name ,code coverage etc reflecting.I have seen over their the Code coverage as 0%.